# A problem with two SwiftUI Pickers in same view

Tags: swift, swiftui, picker

I am pretty new to Swift and trying to learn SwiftUI working on a private App.

I have a Form with two SwiftUI Pickers and I test it in the emulator IPhone 11. The build succeeds but every time I select the second Picker the app crashes with error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x7ffee14e4fe8)".

My code is:

```
static let categories = ["a", "b", "c"]
static let shops = ["z", "v", "x", "y"]

@State private var categoryIndex = 0
@State private var shopIndex = 0

var body: some View {
        Form {
            Picker("Category", selection: $categoryIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< Self.categories.count) { index in
                    Text(Self.categories[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
            Picker("Shop", selection: $shopIndex) {
                ForEach(0 ..< Self.shops.count) { index in
                    Text(Self.shops[index]).tag(index)
                }
            }
        }
}
```

I tried to give every Picker an ID but then the Pickers don't work anymore.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Gianpiero